# Setting up proper React Code highlighting in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to find a proper way to highlight React Code in '.js' files so that it is easier to read in Visual Studio Code. The photo below shows a sample file of how a lot of it is in one color, making it hard to read.

I tried using "jsx" extension by TwentyChung and "react-beautify", but neither of them worked. Can someone please assist? :-)

[image]

Comment: Can you set language mode to `JavaScript React` in the bottom bar (click where it says 'JavaScript')? I have no trouble with VSCode highlighting React, and I havn't really done anything to configure it. It pretty much worked out of the box for me. Only thing I did was add the following to user configuration: `"javascript.validate.enable": false`, since the editor chokes on some es6 constructs (spread operator, arrow functions, etc.) with it set to true.

Comment: thanks! I provided more details on what the problem was in the answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JSX highlighting works out of the box in VS code and JSX files are already associated with `JavaScript React` language mode. If you want to enable JSX syntax coloring in `.js` files click on the language name in the status bar and select `JavaScript React` language mode. You can also associate `.js` files with `JavaScript React` if you don't want to do this every time.  Make sure you have the latest version of VS Code.

Comment: turns out the problem was that I somehow enabled "Javascript Atom Gramar" package and it made all the code un-hlighted. After disabling it, everything worked fine per your instructions!

Comment: Also, you need to be using a theme that is compatible with React's syntax. I saw render's returns as all one color until I switched to `Community Material Theme`.

Comment: It also worked for me after I changed my VS Code Workbench Color Theme to **Dark+**. Would be good if there's a list of theme that supports `JavaScript React` language mode.

Answer (score 25):

Change the VS CODE color theme to Dark+ and change the language in bottom status bar to java script react. This worked for me

Comment: I believe changing the language in the bottom status bar to JavaScript React is the only action that's needed!

Comment: (related to phsource comment above): I had to also switch to another theme - was using "Tomorrow Night" and all JSX was red even with the Javascript React language mode set.

Answer (score 14):

Disabling this extension fixed it for me. It specifically happened this day November 17,2022 3 of my workmates were having the same problem.

[image: Disable this]

Comment: That's very strange... It worked... Thanks!

Comment: Also installing previous version works too.

Comment: There's a new update now, updating it fixed the bug for me.

Comment: Interestingly this worked!

Answer (score 5):

Just uninstall this plugin and install it again in the vs code extensions:

```
Name: JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly
```

VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next

Answer (score 3):

I just added this to `settings.json` and it worked for me, so you can give it a try.

```json
"files.associations": {
        "*.js": "typescriptreact"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Me Here is what worked

1. Update the vscode by downloading the latest verrsion

`https://code.visualstudio.com/download`

2.Open Vscode click extension and search this extension

`Javascript Atom Gramar`

```
Just disable the extension.
```

3.Close and open vscode, now u should see colors in your jsx code.

Hope this will help some one in future

Answer (score 1):

disable the extension named `Javascript Atom Grammar` works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please at least describe the steps you have taken.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Language mode as "Javascript React".
2. Go to Settings -> Color theme -> Select "Dark+" theme.

Answer (score 0):

Click: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Change the color theme settings to dark+(default) , it worked for me.

And select the appropriate language from bottom status bar:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

VS Code highlights code via extensions, not with ESLint or Prettier, which are sometimes assumed to do the job. Out of the box, VS Code supports [React and JSX natively](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript). You can also adjust VS Code's `settings.json` file. Here's an example off how that might look:

```
{
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,

    // Solarized-dark theme
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Solarized-dark",

    // Changes the highlight color in solarized-dark, which I can't see
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "editor.selectionBackground": "#5b455e",
      "editorBracketMatch.border": "#555",
      "editorBracketMatch.background": "#5b455e"
    },

    // Number of spaces in a tab
    "editor.tabSize": 2,

    // Insert spaces when pressing Tab. This setting is overriden
    // based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is true.
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,

    // Override whatever the files say and give me 2 spaces per tab
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always"
  }
```

VS Code modifies syntax highlighting automatically, but it's not perfect. You can also adjust the detection by clicking on the auto-detected language on the right side of the bottom toolbar:

[image: VSCode language detection]